# Alarmpi login problem with raspberry pi after initial startup

Tags: noobs

Am stuck. What is the password for Alarmpi login. My raspberry was working fine with username pi and password raspberry. But just found it not working now cause my adorable children tried to log in. help.

Comment: Also related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50454/19949

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Archlinux on ARM", then its root / root. Read the info here: http://archpi.dabase.com/#to-login