# Someone changed the pi password on the RP2. Is there a way to undo it?

Tags: pi-2, ssh, raspbian-jessie

I was stupid enough to leave the RP2 exposed to the internet with the default password (for the momentary sake of convenience) for a very short time and someone (I am assuming an automated scanning program) changed the password for the `pi` user and now I can't log in.

Is there a way to undo it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How can you recover your password?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50454/how-can-you-recover-your-password/50467#50467) which explains how to reset the password.

**HOWEVER** if someone has modified the password there is no way of knowing what else was done.

Either restore from your backup OR do a fresh install - you should have given up on Jessie a year ago - it is unsupported!

The **VERY FIRST** thing I do on ANY installation is change the password!

Comment: I am curious, how do you know I am on Jessie?

Comment: @AngryHacker you tagged your post with "Raspbian-Jessie" - I assume this is true.

Comment: @Milliways Ahhh, yes.  I am installing OctoPrint distribution which comes with Jessie afaik.

Comment: @Milliways Anyways, the password recover didn't work because whoever hacked me set the disk into read-only mode.  Consequently `passwd pi` wouldn't work.  At least I was able to copy everything off the disk. And then, as you recommended, I just reinstalled everything.

Comment: just be careful with the data you copied off, there could be malicious code in there