# Reset root password Pi4 Raspbian

Tags: pi-4, password, root

A newbie error I made when changing `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99qt5ct` stopped my Pi 4 booting without a password. Which of course I have forgotten/lost!

From what I could find searching, most of the info on changing `cmdline.txt` in boot relates to the earlier Pi's and not the 4.

Do I understand correctly: the Pi 4 has some of the boot info, including the root password held on the SOC? And if correct - is there a way to change it?

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS (like most Debian OS) does not have a root password. The OS behaves the same on all Pi.

Comment: Do you set a password for user **root** by yourself?

Comment: Yes. I did change the "Pi" password - some time back. That is the one I have forgotten. I have attempted modifying the cmdline.txt. Inserteing init=/bin/sh after rootwait. The result was the usual stream of text as the OS loaded but that stopped with a flashing "-" and no option to enter text

Comment: Maybe of use: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985

Comment: Did that "stream of text" contain any error messages?

Comment: This all happened back in June. Since when I have reverted to a fresh install and this time kept a note of my PW

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't changed your password before then your password may be `raspberry` which is the default password for user `pi`.

If you want to change the default password then use `passwd` command. Documentation [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md#:%7E:text=Change%20your%20password&text=Enter%20passwd%20on%20the%20command,displayed%20while%20entering%20your%20password).

Answer (score 0):

> including the root PW held on the SOC

[Technically passwords are not stored anywhere](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50457/5538).  Point being, if you have privileged access to the root filesystem, you can *remove or replace* a password without having to know what it is, and without the system running (eg., if you put the SD card in another computer):

[How can we change root password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985)

However, there is no means of recovering a forgotten password because, once again, it isn't actually stored anywhere.

> Raspberry Pi OS (like most Debian OS) does not have a root password.

To elaborate on some of the material from the other links and clarify a possible point of confusion, there are two "user with no password" scenarios, depending on what's in `/etc/shadow`.

The default entry for root on Raspbian/RpiOS:

```
root:*:18297:0:99999:7:::
```

The second field is an asterisk, and as per `man 5 shadow`, "the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in" (and there are no other ways to log in on a default Pi).  However, if the second field were *empty*:

```
root::18297:0:99999:7:::
```

Then **"no passwords are required** to authenticate as the specified login name" (just hit enter when asked for one).  This is the trick used in the Unix & Linux exchange answer linked above.